# How to pass an attribute for filter in date_based generic views in django

Tags: django, django-generic-views, django-filters

I am using date based generic views for my blog application. I want to use these generic views for displaying all the blogs of a particular user archived according to the date. For this the url that I have to use looks like this

```
 url(r'^archive/month/(?P<year>\d+)/(?P<month>\w+)$',
        'django.views.generic.date_based.archive_month',
        {
            'queryset': Entry.objects.all(), 
            'date_field': 'pub_date',
        },
        name='blog_archive_month',
       ),
```

Is there a way I can pass an attribute in this url, that can be used to filter the objects. I want to something like this

```
 url(r'^(?P<creator_id>\d+)/archive/month/(?P<year>\d+)/(?P<month>\w+)$',
        'django.views.generic.date_based.archive_month',
        {
            'queryset': Entry.objects.filter(creator.id = creator_id), 
            'date_field': 'pub_date',
        },
        name='blog_archive_month',
       ),
```

Is this legal? If it is not then is there any other way of doing the same thing, without having to make my own custom view. I looked at the documentation and I couldn't find anything there.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally make a view for it. There's too much logic happening in yor urls file in my opinion. Here's what you'd return in your view if you were doing a straight object list for example:

```
return object_list(request, q, paginate_by=20, extra_context={})
```

Comment: I can make a custom view but then what about the date based archiving how can I implement that in my view?